# Property 'initGradient' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am building a website with react and typescript. I am having trouble implementing a gradient background that I found on -"https://kevinhufnagl.com/how-to-stripe-website-gradient-effect/".
When I initialise the gradient, I am getting an error "**Property 'initGradient' does not exist on type 'Gradient'**" The error is raised at 'initGradient' in the code below

This is the code I have written:
`

```
function App() {
  <script src="./Gradient"></script>;
  const gradient = new Gradient();
  gradient.initGradient("#gradient-canvas");
  return (

    <div>
      <canvas
        id="gradient-canvas"
        className="absolute w-50 h-50"
        ></canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;`
```

I have created a file 'Gradient.js' which has the code taken from the website linked above. I have also implemented the necessary styling in App.css

I have used the same code to create a website using standard HTML and CSS and was able to implement it correctly. However, I am now trying to build the site in React and Typescript. I have also used tailwind in this project.
Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated cause I've spent way too long trying to implement this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I spent about 6 hours today using various mesh gradient implementations with React before I ended up with this

Gradient component:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const canvasElement = document.getElementById("gradient-canvas");
    const gradient: any = new Gradient();
    if (canvasElement) {
        gradient.initGradient("#gradient-canvas");
    } else {
        gradient.pause();
    }
}, []);
```

CSS

```
canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    --gradient-color-1: #c3e4ff;
    --gradient-color-2: #6ec3f4;
    --gradient-color-3: #eae2ff;
    --gradient-color-4: #b9beff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working for me. Can I ask why setTimeout has been used? I removed setTimeout and it still works. Also there is a small delay between the rendering of all the components and the background animation, is there any way to get the background animation to render at the same time as all the other components. I removed the setTimeout and there's still a delay.

Comment: Yeah I ended up making some edits after I sent that. I edited my original response. I also have the opacity fade in with a transition but the delay is just the gradient loading

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to import the Gradient.js file by using a script tag? If thats the case, you should use a module import.

```
import gradient from './Gradient'

function App() {
  gradient.initGradient("#gradient-canvas");

  return (

    <div>
      <canvas
        id="gradient-canvas"
        className="absolute w-50 h-50"
        ></canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;`
```

As for the `gradient.initGradient("#gradient-canvas");` I would have to see the actual Gradient.js file to see if that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The Gradient.js file can be found here: "https://kevinhufnagl.com/how-to-stripe-website-gradient-effect/" If you go to the bottom of the page, there is a button to download the code, in that folder there is a Gradient.js file. I copied this file into my src folder and had to suppress 'es-lint no used expression'. I also put an `export default Gradient` at the end of the Gradient.js code - not sure if this is correct though.

Comment: hey could you please have a quick look at this and let me know how I could do it? I added `
const gradient = new Gradient();
gradient.initGradient("#gradient-canvas");` to the Gradient.js file and then imported './Gradient'. This worked once but then stopped working.

Comment: Have you tried the above solution of setting a timeout?

Comment: Yes i tried to implement it and it is working.. There is a small delay in the rendering of the background animation as compared to other components but it still works fine. I am trying to find a way to make the animation render quicker. would appreciate any help, thanks